# Expected expression error with `[]`

Tags: c, arrays, function-calls

My prototype for the function

```
int ConvertUserColorToInteger(char [][7] , char [] );

int main (void)
{
```

This is my definition of the Function

```
      char COLOR_CODES[10][7] = {"black", "brown", "red", "orange", "yellow",   "green", "blue", "violet", "gray", "white"};
       char userColor1[10];
       char userColor2[10];
       char userColor3[10];
```

This is my invocation for my function and this is also the thing i am having errors with

```
     ConvertUserColorToInteger(COLOR_CODES[][7], userColor[]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are calling the function in wrong way. In your case, you should write

```
 ConvertUserColorToInteger(COLOR_CODES, userColor1);
```

instead of

```
 ConvertUserColorToInteger(COLOR_CODES[][7], userColor[]);
```

as you need to pass a pointer to the array of type `char[7]` and `char`, respectively, while making the call.